# How to format data for 1d CNN?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset that I need to use with a 1d CNN, however I am not sure how to structure the data dimensions so that I can be used with the 1d CNN.

The data has 5 output classes, however, the input data is where I'm unsure how to proceed. Each output has a matrix of data associated with it, that is 16 x 8000. In other words, for every output I have, there is an associated matrix of numbers that must be fed together to reach that output. I have multiple of these data 16 x 1800 matrices for different samples, from which I am trying to make a prediction.

I was wondering how I can create a data frame for this that can be passed into a 1-d CNN?
More specifically, what would the input_shape parameter be set to in the model?

Right now, I am thinking that my output will be (# samples, 5). My input would be along the lines of ( # samples, (16 x 1800)), but I don't know how this would be implemented in keras?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If each output is the result of an input of shape `16 x 8000`, then you already have your 1D CNN input shape: `16 x 8000 = 128000`.

Comment: @Djinn so would i need to flatten each input array into one row, so the dimensions  of the entire data frame become (#samples, 128000) for the dataframe being fed into the 1d CNN?

Comment: @Balaji I have just been trying to create my data frame to get it into the format I described above, just wasn't sure what exactly the data frame needs to look like before I can feed it in

Comment: Yes, you'd flatten it, essentially. Or you could use 2D CNN (and skip flattening) if you feel striding over two dimensions of data wouldn't change much.

Comment: Please note that the input shape for a Conv1D is (samples, width, channels), you need to decide how to interpret width and channels in your data, we cannot tell you how to do this as you own the data. And flattening makes no sense here.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy how would i structure the input data data frame without flattening? I would need to have a data frame where each row contains a the 16 x 1800 matrix right? I was just thinking about flattening, as Djinn mentioned, and then defining the input shape to (#samples, 1800, 16), which would automatically split the input data shape for each sample (row) in the data frame.

Comment: No, if you do that, you would get an error. You need to set the input shape correctly, but do not ask us how we would do it, we do not have this data and we have no idea what each dimension in your data means. This is something you have to interpret.

Comment: More importantly, if your data is already (samples, 16, 800), there is no need to reshape, it is already in the format (samples, width, channels), you just need to decide which dimension is width and which is channels